# How does one use the Accumulo proxy with python bindings?

Tags: python, proxy, accumulo

Looking for some help to set up the Accumulo proxy. The proxy readme points to ../readme for building and installing with the proxy server but ../readme doesn't say anything about the proxy :)

my goal is to prototype a small python app that calls the accumulo api using the proxy. if anyone has done this I would appreciate a brief list of steps prereqs :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out when you build Accumulo, the proxy is also built.

- Configure the $ACCUMULO_HOME/proxy/proxy.properties file ( instance and zookeepers )
- You can then start the server daemon like this:

> ${ACCUMULO_HOME}/bin/accumulo proxy -p
>   ${ACCUMULO_HOME}/proxy/proxy.properties

- [Install](http://toomuchdata.com/2012/06/25/how-to-install-python-2-7-3-on-centos-6-2/) the correct version of python.
- On some node you need to [install](http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftInstallation) thrift and have access to its libraries.
- Also you need to install the python thrift [packages](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/thrift/0.9.0) ( sudo pythonx.x setup.py install )
- Make sure your thrift and python versions match for the required ***version*** of Accumulo you are using. thrift 0.9.0 and [python 2.6+](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1762) for Accumulo 1.5.0
- [Generate](http://thrift.apache.org/) the python bindings ( thrift --gen py $ACCUMULO_HOME/proxy/thrift/proxy.thrift )
  -Run the example client

> ```
> $PYTHONPATH=path/to/generated/api:path/to/thrift/libs python TestClient.py
> ```

[ I put the generated bindings and thrift libs in /usr/local so it would look something like this, also note that I needed the thrift module in site-packages on the path ]

```
$PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/include/gen-py/:/usr/local/lib/:/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/ python2.7 proxy/examples/python/TestClient.py
```

Hope that helps people new to thrift that hope to do stuff in python :)

Comment: You shouldn't have to generate the python bindings, they should already be in: ${ACCUMULO_HOME}/proxy/src/main/python/